# Activating a JQuery UI datepicker via remote Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the [JQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), but instead of attaching the datepicker to an `input[type=text]` element, i'm attaching it to an `input[type=hidden]` element. In order to activate the datepicker, I'm using a remote button on the UI that's not a sibling of the input element the datepicker is attached to.

In order to show the datepicker, I'm using a click event handler which executes this code

```
$('input.trial_end_date').datepicker('show');
```

This works to show the datepicker, but whenever I click a date, I get an uncaught javascript exception:

```
Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js:6
e.extend._getInst jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js:6
e.extend._selectDay jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js:6
t.selectDay jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js:6
v.event.dispatch localhost.local/:5
o.handle.u localhost.local/:5
```

However, if I change the `input[type=hidden]` to an `input[type=text]` to allow the datepicker to show when the input element is focused, all click events fire without any problems (until I activate the datepicker via the button, then they all fail no matter which way the datepicker is activated).

Is there a more reliable way to activate the date picker via a remote button and hide the input element for the date? I'm not sure why this exception is being thrown at all.

Here's an example of this not working in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ7Z7/1/). Though, the exception isn't the same. After further research, I seem to have found the reason, which  I'll add in an answer below.

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Added a JSFiddle link to the question for archival purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you use a hidden input when you can instantiate a datepicker on a regular div and just hide and show that div? If you don't need the input, don't use it.

```
<input type="button" id="open" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();

$('#open').on('click', function() {
    $('#datepicker').toggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KekDX/1/)

Comment: I didn't realize I could use it in a div like that, that's certainly better I think. Though, I guess the reason I used the input element is so that the datepicker would automatically update the value of the date selected on the input without me having to manage it myself.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with this problem a bit in a JSFiddle, (http://jsfiddle.net/XJ7Z7/1/), it's apparent that if you attach the datepicker to an input element - the input element must be visible (ie, not a hidden element).

The reason for this is because the Datepicker module tries to position the calendar via `position:absolute;` and to do so accurately needs to get the top/left offset for the input element to which it is attached. A hidden input element has no top/left offset (it's set to 0/0), so therefore the module skips that element to try to find one that is visible that it can use to calculate where to place the calendar.

If there's no sibling element that can be used the reference object gets set to null and an exception is thrown when the datepicker tries to access the left/top properties of the return object of `$(el).offset()` because the call to offset returns a null value.

The solution here is outlined by @adeneo in the accepted answer, but the sacrifice is that you'll have to manage your hidden input value for the selected date on your own via the `onSelect` callback of the datepicker module initialization.

I hope this helps someone out there who is running into a similar problem.

Comment: Actually, you can still achieve it with a textbox and some CSS to hide it. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ7Z7/2/)